# VS Code .sql file colorization/prettify

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code

VS Code is colorizing the script in my .sql files, but with what seem to be some errors. For example I would expect "RENAME" to be colorized here:

[image]

I've tried using a few extensions, but I can't fix this problem. I don't know if it's because I'm using postgreSQL and it's reading some other SQL dialect? Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figure it out. At the bottom right of VS Code, click the button that says 'Postgres' as shown here:
[image]

You can then select/search whichever language you want to use. Mine was on SQL, and I changed it to postgresql.